# Unable to make a automated selection of dates in 'react-native-datepicker' using detox wix library

Tags: react-native, detox

I am unable to make selection of dates and month in 'react-native-datepicker' dialog which is a third party library component in my detox test cases. I am using detox-wix library to write the automated test cases.

I am able to select the text '2018' using the detox's text() matcher method and can select the different which appears in scroll view,

```
await element(by.text('2018')).tap();
```

I am also able to press the 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons using the same by.text() matcher.

```
await element(by.text('OK')).tap();
await element(by.text('Cancel')).tap();
```

But., I am when I am trying to select the dates which are displayed in the datepicker dialog, using the same by.text() mathcer, then it doesn't works.

```
// select the date '21' 
await element(by.text('21')).tap();
```

And also I am unable to change the month by clicking on '<'  buttons. Need a way to select the dates and month.

Comment: Hello @abdul, did you manage to find any solution by scrolling? I've managed to open my scrollview but not able to scroll through it. Read [this](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#scrollpixels-direction-startpositionxnan-startpositionynan) and implemented scroll function, but didn't work either :/

Comment: I also have the same issue. @TommyLeong did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Same issue here with webdriverio did you find how to ?